# HTML/Javascript popup box with table

Tags: javascript, html, popup

In my application I have a button, when the user clicks on the button I want a popup box (not window) to appear with a table populated with information I pass in to it.

I have been looking online and cant seem to find how to do this, or even where to start (use all HTML, use all Javascript, use both HTML and Javascript). Has anyone done something similar to this or know a good starting point for this (e.g. what components to use)?

Comment: Just create the html elements dinamically with javascript, pass the information using functions and make sure the new elements have a higher z-index in css.

Comment: you can use jquery dialog

Comment: where is your table. Please post once

Comment: Have a look over here http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ you can create table inside that `dialog div`

Comment: See this http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: see my answer with demo on jsfiddle :)

Comment: see updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KnrEF/1/) link :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a range of frameworks that'll do the trick for you.

An easy and common one is jQuery Dialog (http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

A small example, given the html:

```
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog" style="display:none">
  <p>Adding the modal overlay screen makes the dialog look more prominent because it dims out the page content.</p>
</div>

<a href="#" id="openDialog">Click me</a>
```

Assuming you've included jQuery and jQuery dialog on top, add the following javascript:

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $( "#openDialog").on("click", function(){ 
       $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
          height: 140,
          modal: true
        });
       $( "#dialog-modal" ).show();
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for this, was able to use the jquery-ui to create the modal dialog then I created a table in this using HTML and passed my records then into the table :)

Answer (score 2):

simply use JQuery

**[See Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/KnrEF/1/)**

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#help_button").click(function() {
            $("#help").slideToggle(1000, function() {
                if($("#help_button").val() == "close")
                {
                    $("#help_button").val("show table");
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#help_button").val("close");
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="help">table populated with information </div>
<input id="help_button" type="button" value="Show Popup"/>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS :**

```
#help{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: this works but it pushes everything on my page down rather then actually giving me a pop up box with the information

Comment: it's not a popup

Answer (score 0):

you can create a pop up like this .. [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/UaUA1VHDQl8x9yErAJKU?p=preview)
and pass the table values inside it.
.

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to use [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/) with this [plugin](http://jquery-plugins.net/bootstrap-dialog-flexible-dialog-for-bootstrap) ([plugin-examples](http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/#examples)) (there you can find a bunch of similar plugin, take a look and choose one )

It is good way to build Your website based on some framework (bootstrap) :)